# Freescale microcontroler bug in C code

Tags: c, microcontroller

I'm currently learning how to use the HC08 series of freescale micro controllers together with the codewarrior IDE (ver. 6.3).
I wrote a simple program but it fails to compile.

```
#include <hidef.h>
#include "derivative.h"

void main(void) {
   EnableInterrupts;

   /* include your code here */
   DDRA |= 0x03;
   PTA |= 0x01;
   unsigned int counter;   << error here "Error : C2801: '}' missing
   counter = 50000;
   while(counter--);
   PTA ^= 0x03;

   for(;;) {
      __RESET_WATCHDOG(); /* feeds the dog */
   }

}
```

Any idea what might be wrong with it? All brackets match. Maybe it is something micro controller specific?

Comment: I've used that IDE & compiler, but don't recall if it supports the 1990 or 1999 C standard. Variable declaration after executable code in a function was not legal before C99. Try moving the variable declaration to the beginning of main.

Comment: @AviBerger please add this comment as an answer, so I can accept it and you get your well deserved points :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used that IDE & compiler, but don't recall if it supports the 1990 or 1999 C standard.

Variable definitions after executable code in a block was not legal before C99. Since this is exactly where you are getting your error message, it appears that the compiler does not support C99. Try moving the variable definition to the beginning of main.

```
void main(void) {    
    unsigned int counter;       
    EnableInterrupts;

    // the rest of the code
}
```

You could also introduce a new block. This is not common & not particularly helpful for your code sample. It is worth pointing out as it applies to the bracketed body of a loop ( or if statement) and is sometimes useful to provide a variable local to such a block.

```
void main(void) {
    EnableInterrupts;

    DDRA |= 0x03;
    PTA |= 0x01;

    {   // start of nested scope
        unsigned int counter;   
        counter = 50000;
        while(counter--);
    }   // "counter" ceases to exist here 

    PTA ^= 0x03;

    for(;;) {
        __RESET_WATCHDOG(); /* feeds the dog */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is probably a C89 compiler or similar. That means variable definitions needs to be at the top of a scope, so:

```
void main(void) {
   unsigned int counter; 
   EnableInterrupts;

   /* include your code here */
   DDRA |= 0x03;
   PTA |= 0x01;
```